# Azure worker role trace to development storage

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am having a lot of difficulty getting trace logs in an Azure WorkerRole written to local development storage (with the ultimate goal being Azure storage once deployed).  I have googled for days and keep finding plenty of examples like this http://forums.asp.net/t/2041817.aspx?Azure+Getting+Trace+Data+to+Azure+Storage.  Unfortunately, even though that discussion is as recent as March of 2015, it still references a solution that is apparently not supported.  The code line

```
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
```

uses the DiagnosticMonitor class which is apparently now deprecated.  I am either not googling the correct things, or there is a startling lack of information on how to configure trace logs in the "newest" supportable fashion.  I can find plenty of information on the old "deprecated" way.

Here is what I have so far.  The app.config for my worker role has this section defined:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

In fact, that was automatically added by the template that created the WorkerRole.  I didn't manually do anything with that section.

The WorkerRole section in ServiceConfiguration.csdef looks like this:

```
<WorkerRole name="Processor" vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
        <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
</WorkerRole>
```

And the related Role section in ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg looks like this:

```
<Role name="Processor">
    <Instances count="1" />
        <ConfigurationSettings>
            <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
```

Then I have a Trace statement in one of the classes in my WorkerRole project that looks like this:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Handling event");
```

The diagnostics.wadcfgx associated with the WorkerRole in the cloud project looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
        <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
          <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" />
        </Directories>
        <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
        </PerformanceCounters>
        <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" />
        </WindowsEventLog>
        <CrashDumps dumpType="Full">
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaAppAgent.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaIISHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WindowsAzureGuestAgent.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaWorkerHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="DiagnosticsAgent.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="w3wp.exe" />
        </CrashDumps>
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount>teststorage</StorageAccount>
  </PublicConfig>
  <PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <StorageAccount name="teststorage" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
  </PrivateConfig>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Azure storage and compute emulator are successfully started when I run the application in Visual Studio.  With all of that, I would expect to go to Server Explorer in Visual Studio, expand the Azure node all the way down to Storage.  Go to the (Development) node and see that there is a table under the Tables node containing my trace logs, but there is nothing there.

[image: Visual Studio IDE]

Clearly I am doing something wrong and have yet to find documentation clear enough, either blog or Microsoft, that explains how to get this working.  So here I am asking what would seem to be something relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using SDK Version 2.5/2.5.1 and it does not support diagnostics in emulator. Please see this link for breaking changes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx#BKMK_breaking. From this link:

> Diagnostics logs are not collected in the Azure compute emulator – For
>   projects that target the Azure SDK version 2.5, the Azure compute
>   emulator no longer supports the collection of diagnostics logs,
>   including performance counters, infrastructure logs, IIS logs, and
>   event logs. In addition, logs are no longer stored in Azure storage or
>   development storage. You can continue to view application logs in the
>   Visual Studio Output window or the compute emulator. This only affects
>   projects that target Azure SDK version 2.5; projects that continue to
>   target Azure SDK 2.4 are not affected.

So, as of today your options are:

- Target your project to use SDK Version 2.4.
- Do your testing in cloud only.
- Wait for next SDK version hoping that this issue will be fixed there.

Comment: Well that was a very quick, albeit unfortunate answer.  Thanks for the help.  I sure would like to test that everything is setup and configured correctly locally before publishing to Azure.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you are and it sucks! Not having the ability to test locally is like shooting in the dark and hoping for it to work. For now, we're sticking with SDK 2.4.